# How to pass Thread count and loop count to next thread group from a Beanshell post processor

Tags: jmeter

I have a setUp thread Group where i run a jdbc request to fetch the records. Then i use a beanshell post processor to fix the Thread count and Loop count then pass to next thread group as a property.

My codes are given below.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;

int  totalRecords = Integer.valueOf(vars.get("UCID_#")).intValue(); //UCID - Column name

if(totalRecords<100){
   int noOfThreads = 5;
   int loopCount = (totalRecords/noOfThreads);
}

JMeterUtils.setProperty("noOfThreads", noOfThreads);
JMeterUtils.setProperty("loopCount", loopCount");
```

In next thread group i use above properties to fix number of threads and loop count.

```
${__property(noOfThreads)}
${__property(loopCount)}
```

If i run the test i am getting below error.

```
ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;  //jmeter spe . . . '' : Undefined argument: noOfThreads 
Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;  //jmeter spe . . . '' : Undefined argument: noOfThreads
```

Then i tried below steps as well, but its not working

```
${__setProperty(noOfThreads,vars.get("noOfThreads"))};
${__setProperty(loopCount,vars.get("loopCount"))};
```

Someone please help me to solve this issue...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `noOfThreads` is local variable of `if` block, you cannot access it outside `if` block.

You can do like this:

```java
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;

int totalRecords = Integer.valueOf(vars.get("UCID_#")).intValue(); //UCID - Column name

int noOfThreads = 1;
int loopCount  = 1;

if(totalRecords<100){
   noOfThreads = 5;
   loopCount = (totalRecords/noOfThreads);
}

JMeterUtils.setProperty("noOfThreads", noOfThreads);
JMeterUtils.setProperty("loopCount", loopCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all using of Beanshell sampler is discouraged in JMeter and it is not recommended while running load test.

You should use JSR223 sampler/post/pre-processor for writing your custom logic in the script

Below is the code that will store the value into property where you can use ${__P()} or props.get() function to retrieve in different threadgroup(s) in the same test plan

```
def  totalRecords=Integer.valueOf(vars.get("UCID_val"))
def noOfThreads=5
def loopCount


if(totalRecords<100){
   loopCount=(totalRecords/noOfThreads)
}

//Setting the value to property
props.put("pNoOfThreads", String.valueOf(noOfThreads));
props.put("pLoopCount", String.valueOf(loopCount));
```

[image]
[image]

Alternatively, you can use vars.putObject(); to store and vars.getObject() to retrieve it.

Comment: Am not running Load testing , its a kind of automation to run sequence of SQL queries and APIs to feed the data for load testing. That's why i chose Beanshell as it's easy to me rather than Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put last 2 lines inside the [if block](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions.asp) because `noOfThreads` and `loopCount` variables [are only accessible](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_scope.asp) there.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;

int totalRecords = Integer.valueOf(vars.get("UCID_#")).intValue(); //UCID - Column name

if (totalRecords < 100) {
    int noOfThreads = 5;
    int loopCount = (totalRecords / noOfThreads);
    JMeterUtils.setProperty("noOfThreads", noOfThreads);
    JMeterUtils.setProperty("loopCount", "loopCount");
}
```

Also be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting).

If your code is executed by 1 thread only somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) it should be fine but in case you will be conducting the load from code or use "heavy" cryptographic operations it worth considering migrating to Groovy.

More information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)

Comment: Am not running Load testing , its a kind of automation to run sequence of SQL queries and APIs to feed the data for load testing. That's why i chose Beanshell as it's easy to me rather than Groovy.